# Is there any way to lock the camera on an enemy?

Tags: assassins-creed-3

I'm having a bit of trouble adapting to the new combat engine.  The Arkham Asylum-style combat is not a problem, but the *camera* is giving me trouble.  It seems to stay put, even if I'm targeting an enemy in the foreground...even if they run off-screen, in fact.  There doesn't appear to be a formal 'lock-on' like there was in previous installments, but is there any way to keep the camera turned towards my active target?  This is really making my life difficult.

Comment: So, I've gotten a little more used to it, but I still have trouble seeing enemies in the foreground sometimes (especially if there's a building or something around.)  Would love to discover a trick for this...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, unlike in previous Assassin's Creed games, there is no way to lock the camera on an enemy.